# How to make home directory the root with useradd on Debian

Tags: debian, document-root, home-directory

I want to add a new user on a Debian server but I need to set, that it sees the home directory to be the root for security purposes.

e.g.:

new user: `usr` home directory: `/home/usr` root directory: `/home/usr` and it should not be able to go back to `/home`

Is there a way to do that using `useradd`? Or even manually?

Comment: https://wiki.debian.org/chroot

Comment: @marekful I tried that, but I didn't really understand what to do, It downloaded a whole debian system to my /home directory but changed nothing else. If you know how it works, could you please give me a pointer?

Comment: @marekful I also tried the following `chroot --userspec=1001:0 /home/upload`  and got the following error: `chroot: failed to run command `/bin/bash': No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot do that directly with useradd.

You have to play with chmod. For example you could revoke the 'read others' right in /home to block direcory listing.

Do not revoke the execute right or you won't be able to cd in users homes.

But if you want to put restrictions on users remotely connecting to your server, you may setup a 'chroot jail' for SSH access for example

Comment: I tried that, but all I could accomplish, is to not list files and directories. The user can still `cd` into say `etc` if he wants. (I changed both `/home` and `/`  to 711)

Comment: Yes, but you cannot block the 'cd' right, only the list right, because it could block the access to all subdirectories and you may endup with an unusable system, especially if you try to block /etc. Be very careful...

Comment: Do you need to restrict users connecting remotely to your server?

Comment: I got the task of creating a user on a virtual server that can ftp into a specific directory (i.e: `/home/upload` <- on localhost) but could not reach `/home` from there

Comment: So you have to configure properly your ftp server. For example for vsftpd, your have to add the option: chroot_local_user=Yes

Comment: I read through the `vsftpd.conf` and this should work, yet it doesn't seem to change anything. I can still just as easily exit the directory